# Why is layout_weight not working in TextInputLayout' children?

Tags: android, xml

I have the following:

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:alpha=".9"
        android:background="@color/light_gray_search"
        android:padding="16dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/myImage" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/myAutoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/myAutoHint"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Knowing that `TextInputLayout` **extends** `LinearLayout`, and I'm using `LinearLayout` xml attributes (`weightSum`, `orientation`, `layout_weight`) to have a horizontal allignment of my imageView first, followed by the autoCompleteText,

**Why is this not working?**

Current result: Both image and text are literally zero width even after assigning a `layout_weight`.

Comment: I think you need to extend `TextInputLayout` class and do your customization or use other layouts ,also this line is on `TextInputLayout` constractor `setOrientation(VERTICAL);`

Comment: @MohammedAlaa found the answer actually. Posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer actually, posting it here for future references:

Adding a `LinearLayout`, and have children of the `LinearLayout` be `ImageView` and `TextInputLayout` on a horizontal orientation, respectively.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

<ImageView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.1"
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/myImage"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
..  
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.9"
..>  

<AutoCompleteTextView
../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```